# Tidying up VBA, Making VBA automatic based on cells

Tags: vba, excel

i am self taught with VBA and still have a very basic Knowledge but learning Quickly

I Have 3 Sheets in 1 Workbook,

"Purchase Control"

"Material Index Sheet"

"Manufacturing"

This Works Manually but this isnt good as these documents are constantly updated, Column 'P' hold Test Certificates which are acquired later, with this i need the rows to copy to the "Material Index Sheet" and "Manufacturing", if the test Cert is changed it also updates on the next sheets.

i also need something that adds rows for me, instead of having my data be hardcopied B8:P200 which some of these documents dont have 200 rows.

**Sub *MaterialProcess* Code**

```
Sub MaterialProcess()

'Filter Based on Test Certs being Filled in
ActiveSheet.Range("$B$8:$P$202").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:="<>"

'Copy all Relevant Cells Based Above
Worksheets("Purchase Control").Range("B9:P200").Copy

Worksheets("Material Index Sheet").Range("$B$9:$P$200").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 'it pastes that row and doesnt affect any other row'
Worksheets("Purchase Control").Range("B9:H200").Copy
Worksheets("Manufacturing").Range("B9:H200").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("Purchase Control").Range("$B$8:$P$8").AutoFilter Field:=15

'New Customer
Range("D3:E3").Select         'Merged Cells'
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Material Index Sheet").Select
Range("D3:E3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Manufacturing").Select
Range("D3:E3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

'Contract Review
Sheets("Purchase Control").Select
Range("D5:E5").Select         'Merged Cells'
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Material Index Sheet").Select
Range("D5:E5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Manufacturing").Select
Range("D5:E5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

'Order Num
Sheets("Purchase Control").Select
Range("G3").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Material Index Sheet").Select
Range("G3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Manufacturing").Select
Range("G3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

'Working Order
Sheets("Purchase Control").Select
Range("G5").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Material Index Sheet").Select
Range("G5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Manufacturing").Select
Range("G5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

'Unit
Sheets("Purchase Control").Select
Range("I4").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Material Index Sheet").Select
Range("I4").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Manufacturing").Select
Range("I4").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

This Private Sub allows us to Track anything that is getting manufactured by colour: Red, Yellow, Green,

I am able to get the Date the cell was doubleclicked To yellow or green, this also forces a comment to be added, any information can be commented for the job.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim MyRange As Range

'(1) Desired Range where it works:
Set MyRange = Range("$I$9:$Q$50")
Cancel = True

'(1) Check if double clicked cell is one where the code should work:
If Not Intersect(Target, MyRange) Is Nothing Then
    Custom_ColourChange Target
End If

End Sub


'(2) Changed from default Worksheet_Selection event to Custom Sub:
Private Sub Custom_ColourChange(ByVal Target As Range)

'If the target cell is clear
If Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
    'Double Click Turns Red
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

'But if the target cell is already Red
ElseIf Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
    'Double click Turns Yellow
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6

'But if the target cell is already Yellow
ElseIf Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
    'Then change the background to Green
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 4

'But if the target cell is already Green
ElseIf Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 4 Then
    'Then clear the background color
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last row in a spreadsheet with the following code:

```
dim wSheet as Worksheet : Set wSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SHEETNAME")
dim lastRow : lastRow = wSheet.Cells(wSheet.Rows.Count,"B").End(xlUp).Row
```

This would allow you to copy only the populated rows with

`Worksheets("Purchase Control").Range("B9:P" & lastRow).Copy`

You can easily get the date of the double click with a

`dateTimeClicked = Now`

which can then be pushed into whatever cell/comment/wherever you need